# Extracting HTTP status codes from the MethodOutcome/ outcome of a create operation in HAPI FHIR

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi

I want to extract the HTTP status of a HAPI FHIR create Method.

```
MethodOutcome outcome = client.create().resource(medicationOrders[0]).prettyPrint().encodedXml().execute();
```

Is there any way to recover it from the MethodOutcome or any other workaround exists?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that can be useful..

If the method returns successfully, then you have gotten an HTTP 2xx response back. There isn't a way to tell if it was a 200 or a 204 for example, but it was a successful response.

If the method throws a [BaseServerResponseException](http://hapifhir.io/apidocs/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/server/exceptions/BaseServerResponseException.html) of some sort, the server returned a 4xx or 5xx status code. You can call `BaseServerResponseException#getStatusCode()` to find out which one.

If you need to know the exact response in all cases, you can use a [client interceptor](http://hapifhir.io/apidocs/ca/uhn/fhir/rest/client/IClientInterceptor.html) to find that.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain status code using Kotlin like this with client interceptors,

1. Create an interceptor to pick status codes,

   ```
    private fun createClientInterceptor(statusCodes: MutableList<Int>): 
        IClientInterceptor {
            return object : IClientInterceptor {
                override fun interceptRequest(theRequest: IHttpRequest?) {}
                override fun interceptResponse(theResponse: IHttpResponse?) {
                    if (theResponse != null) {
                        println(theResponse.status)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
   ```
2. Create a client and register the interceptor

   ```
    val ctx = FhirContext.forR4()!!
    val restfulGenericClient =  ctx.newRestfulGenericClient(getServerUrl())
    restfulGenericClient.registerInterceptor(createClientInterceptor(statusCodes))
   ```

In this way, you can collect status codes of responses in Kotlin, appropriately you can change the code to Java as well.